# How to add space between text in SMS in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, sms

I am developing a SMS integration with PHP(curl), I have one issue regarding the SMS text spaces, as variable $fadd hold an address of a user with some street-name,lane,state etc.
Example: $fadd=abc street abc lane abc state.
But in a actual SMS the spaces between street lane and state gets disapeared.
such as
Example: abcstreetabclaneabcstate.
so how can i add spaces in a address that is stored in a variable?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
        $driver_name=$_POST['driver_name'];
        $vehicle=$_POST['vehicle'];
        $two_values = explode('_', $_POST['driver_name']);
        $ticket_id=$_POST['ticket_id'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $fadd=$_POST['fadd'];

        $var="user=user&password=password&sender=sender&sendercdma=1234567890&text=".$ticket_id."+".$fname."+".$fadd."+".$phone."+".$date."+".$time."&PhoneNumber=91".$two_values[1]."&track=1";

    echo $var;

    $curl=curl_init('http://sms.manddigitalsolutions.com/sendsms.asp');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result= curl_exec($curl);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($curl);
    die("SMS has sent.....");
                 echo '<script language="javascript">';
                 echo 'alert("Success....!"); location.href="assigndriver.php"';
                 echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is your variable $fadd=$_POST['fadd']; contains proper address with spaces ?

Comment: @Mayank Pandey Yes!

Comment: $var =urlencode($var); and pass it

Comment: You have to escape your POST variables, you've probably seen this in URLs, spaces get replaced by %20 and so on. Check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: try my answer @user1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple use `urlencode`

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page. [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

urlencode manage the space and all the things how you given a text in proper.

```
$fadd = urlencode($fadd);
$var="user=user&password=password&sender=sender&sendercdma=1234567890&text=".$ticket_id."+".$fname."+".$fadd."+".$phone."+".$date."+".$time."&PhoneNumber=91".$two_values[1]."&track=1";
```

Comment: but same thing iwant to apply for this- $two_values = explode('_', $_POST['driver_name']); ....it doesnt work!

Answer (score 1):

Try one thing, change this line:

```
$var="user=user&password=password&sender=sender&sendercdma=1234567890&text=".$ticket_id."+".$fname."+".$fadd."+".$phone."+".$date."+".$time."&PhoneNumber=91".$two_values[1]."&track=1";
```

to

```
$var = urlencode("user=user&password=password&sender=sender&sendercdma=1234567890&text=".$ticket_id."+".$fname."+".$fadd."+".$phone."+".$date."+".$time."&PhoneNumber=91".$two_values[1]."&track=1");
```

> urlencode is necessary otherwise characters like space will not
>   properly rendered.

and try again

Comment: by doing this, SMS sending failed....Invalid user name/password error...

Answer (score 0):

use urlencode() before assign in $var

```
$var = urlencode("user=user&password=password&sender=sender&sendercdma=1234567890&text=".$ticket_id."+".$fname."+".$fadd."+".$phone."+".$date."+".$time."&PhoneNumber=91".$two_values[1]."&track=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

UrlEncode your text, then it works fine.

```
$text= "Sms send successfully, copy and past the code and check";
$message= urlencode($text);
smsApiBeta($contact_number, $message);
```